# What is the command line to install djoser on anaconda

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, anaconda, djoser

What is the command line to install djoser library on anaconda?

I have tried `conda install djoser` but no package found

Answer (score 1):

There is [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/547) requesting someone package it for Conda, so it doesn't appear to have a Conda build. If you would like it packaged, I'd also encourage you to make a package request on [Conda Forge's `staged-recipes` repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues).

In the meantime you can still install it via `pip`. E.g.,

```bash
conda activate foo  # activate your environment
conda install pip   # ensure pip is installed here
pip install djoser
```

Please note that using `pip` in Conda environments is not without caveats, and generally should not be used in the **base** env. See [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `conda install -c conda-forge djoser`.